# Attempt to read property "usertype" on null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-9

In my system, there are two different dashboards. One for admin and another one for user. In my database there is a column name `usertype` and there are two `int` values. `1` is for the admin and `0` is for the users. In my laravel project if the login user trying to access their dashboard then firstly in controller file it will check if he/she is admin or not. If his/her assigned `usertype` value is `1` then he/she will redirect to the admin dashboard, if it is not `1` then he/she will redirect to the user dashboard. But I got an error

> Attempt to read property `usertype` on `null`".

The admincontroller code for dashboard redirection are given below

```
public function admindashboard(){
    if(Auth::user()->usertype == 1 ){
        return view('admin/pages/admindashboard');
    }
    else{
        return view('viewer.pages.userpanel.userdashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: `Auth::user()` is returning `null` which suggests that you're not authenticated (logged in). You can confirm this by using `dd(Auth::user());` before your `if` statement.

Comment: Why not create a middleware for that. Maybe **RedirectIfNotAdmin** and **RedirectIfAdmin**

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to make middleware for admin and normal user. But if you want to continue with your existing code, check for Auth::user() also in if condition like this.

```
public function admindashboard(){
    if(!empty(Auth::user()) && Auth::user()->usertype == 1 ){
        return view('admin/pages/admindashboard');
    }
    return view('viewer.pages.userpanel.userdashboard');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use middleware in the controller of each control panel and determine the access level there. The user [rights package](https://spatie/laravel-permission) can help you with this.

Example of use inside the controller:

```
class AdminDashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('admin');
    }
}
```

[Example](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/blade-directives#content-roles) of use inside the blade (without using controller:):

```
@role('admin')
    <x-panels.admin />
@else
    <x-panels.user />
@endrole
```